# Validate an input field in order to be unique and non duplicate in jQuery mobile

Tags: validation, jquery-mobile, unique

In my jQuery mobile app  I have an alarm  service the user enter number of alarms Per day , once the user enters the number of alarms lets say 3 , app  will create 3 input fields for time , when the user clicks save button to save data i need to validate all the created input time fields so the entered time not equal the current time,  and be unique there is no alarms at this time , I have solved it by the following code but the problem is that when the user enter a unique time " a non repeated time" I change the exist value from true to false but it didn't enter and execute this condition

else if (exist == false  && $(this).attr('value') != currentTime  )  directly "once " the exist value is updated ,I need to click the save button again in order to make the code know that the exist value is changed , and  continue saving  the alarm data  in the DB .

How can i solve this problem ? please help me ...

```
<body>

<div data-role="page"   id="Alarm">
<div data-role="header" ></div>
<div data-role="content" >


 <form>

   <input type="number"  id="AlarmTimes"/>
   <label for="AlarmTimes" > Number of alarms Per day </lable>
   <div   id="timeFields"  style="display:none;" >

   </div>
   <div>
     <input type="button" id="SaveBtn" value="Save Alarm "/></div>
    </form>
 </div>
 </div>

</body>
```

javascript

```
var alarm_TimesNum;
var exist = true;

var ExistAlarmTimesArr = [];



$('#AlarmTimes').on('keyup' , function(){

    alarm_TimesNum = $('#AlarmTimes').attr('value');

    var timeFields = $('#timeFields');   

    if(timeFields.children().length != 0 )
    {   
       timeFields.empty();                                
       timeFields.hide();
    } 


    for( var i=1 ; i<= alarm_TimesNum ;i++)
    {

       timeFields.append($( '<div class="ui-grid-a" ><div class="ui-block-a"> <input  type="time" name="alarmTime"    class="AlarmTime" /></div>' 
    +'<div class="ui-block-b" ><label for=" alarmTime"  ><font  size="5px"  style="font- weight: normal;" class="Time_label"> Time:: </font></label></div></div>'));


       timeFields.trigger('create');
    }


    timeFields.show();


 });


 db.transaction(getExistAlarmsTime,transError,transSuccess);

 $('#SaveBtn').on('click',function(){


     $('.AlarmTime').each(function(i){

     if( $(this).attr('value') == currentTime || $.trim(   $(this).attr('value')).length ==0 )
         {  
        $('.Time_label').each(function(j){  if(j==i){        $(this).addClass('missing');}  });
            if(i==0){ alert('Enter time for alarm 1 '); }
    else if(i==1){alert('Enter time for alarm 2 ');  }
    else if(i==2){alert('Enter time for alarm 3 ');   }

      }
          else if( $(this).attr('value') != currentTime && exist ==   true )
      {   
          for( var k=0;k<ExistAlarmTimesArr.length;k++)
               {  
                   if( $(this).attr('value') == ExistAlarmTimesArr[k])
           {
                    $('.Time_label').each(function(j){  if(j==i){        $(this).addClass('missing');}  });

                        if(i==0){alert( 'Enter Another Time  for alarm 1 you have another alarm at this time '); }
                else if(i==1){ alert( 'Enter Another Time  for alarm 2 you have another alarm at this time ');  }
                else if(i==2){   alert( 'Enter Another Time  for alarm 3 you have another alarm at this time ');   }

                         exist = true;
             break;
                }

                    else { exist = false;   }

    }
   }
       else if (exist == false  && $(this).attr('value') != currentTime  )
    {
           $('.Time_label').each(function(j){  if(j==i){ $(this).removeClass('missed');}    });
        NotifTime = $(this).attr('value');

         TimeArr[j] = NotifTime;
       j= j+1 ;
       count ++;
     }  

      });

     // save data in the DB
 });






 function getExistAlarmsTime(tx)
 {
     tx.executeSql("SELECT Time  FROM AlarmTBL ",[],AlarmTimeExist,transError);


 }

 function AlarmTimeExist(tx,result)
 {

    for(var j=0;j< result.rows.length; j++)
{
        var row = result.rows.item(j);

    ExistAlarmTimesArr[j] = row['Time'];

     }

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue could just be the use of `.attr('value')`, try subbing it for `.val()` instead. I think that will fix your issues.

Comment: Thanks for help ,I have tried it but the problem still , the change of exist variable value from true to false noticed by the code when i click the save button again

Comment: Please can you help me more??

Comment: Sorry I can't do much more with it, there are a lot of issues.

Comment: Ummm *label instead of lable *wrap js that depends on dom in document.ready or (function() {})(); *lots references to attr instead of val *variable db is not instantiated before use *The on click handler really should call preventDefault *variable currentTime is never instantiated *use `alert('Enter time for alarm ' + i)` *on click handler should call functions, apply SRP more. *use `new Date()` and string split the input to do your != currentTime. That or use a plugin cause you can never trust a user to input in a particular format.